# How to make sure queue is empty before exiting main thread

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a program that has two threads, the main thread and one additional that works on handling jobs from a FIFO queue.
Something like this:

```
import queue
import threading

q = queue.Queue()

def _worker():
  while True:
      msg = q.get(block=True)
      print(msg)
      q.task_done()

t = threading.Thread(target=_worker)
#t.daemon = True
t.start()

q.put('asdf-1')
q.put('asdf-2')
q.put('asdf-4')
q.put('asdf-4')
```

What I want to accomplish is basically to make sure the queue is emptied before the main thread exits.
If I set *t.daemon* to be True the program will exit before the queue is emptied, however if it's set to False the program will never exit. Is there some way to make sure the thread running the *_worker()* method clears the queue on main thread exit?

Comment: I am not a concurrent programming expert, but maybe, you need to add `t.join()` at the end of program to make the main thread wait till `t` finishes its execution.

Comment: @ozgur: the thread will never terminate, infinite loop.. so using join won't work - https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Comment: Why did you call `block=True` on `q.get`? It won't quit even when queue is emptied.

Comment: @ozgur: easier code, I don't need to catch queue.Empty and retry all over again. I think this is a use case where actually block=True is intended to be used.. please correct me if I'm worng

Comment: Did you try adding `q.join()` at the end and uncommenting `t.deamon = True`? Maybe you might want to look into `atexit` module to actually clear the queue at program exit.

Comment: @ozgur: yea I tried that, as I said, it won't work because the thread is executing an infinite loop. I have also glanced at atexit, but not sure how I can kill the thread safely when that happens.. is there some termination signal one can send and catch within the thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments touch on using `.join()`, but depending on your use case, using a join may make threading pointless.

I assume that your main thread will be doing things other than adding items to the queue - and may be shut down at any point, you just want to ensure that your queue is empty before shutting down is complete.

At the end of your main thread, you could add a simple empty check in a loop.

```
while not q.empty():
    sleep(1)
```

If you don't set `t.daemon = True` then the thread will never finish. Setting the thread as a daemon thread will mean that the thread does not cause your program to stay running when the main thread finishes.

Answer (score 2):

Put a special item (e.g. None) in the queue, that signals the worker thread to stop.

```
import queue
import threading

q = queue.Queue()

def _worker():
  while True:
      msg = q.get(block=True)
      if msg is None:
          return
      print(msg) # do your stuff here

t = threading.Thread(target=_worker)
#t.daemon = True
t.start()

q.put('asdf-1')
q.put('asdf-2')
q.put('asdf-4')
q.put('asdf-4')
q.put(None)
t.join()
```